# Cant find specific URL on server

Tags: php, ftp, routes, opencart

I have to replace a specific design of a checkout page and implement a new design for the checkout page but I cannot find the exact path in the server where to make changes. The URL is :

https://www.infraitshop.com/index.php?route=checkout/cart

What is the route=? part. Please explain what is to be done in this case.

Comment: It's your application. You should be knowing your application URLs plan. `route` here is a parameter that is going to be used by `index.php` , and it looks like this application is applying a front controller design pattern . (every request is going to be handled by `index.php`). Then `index.php` is going to route the request to the sub controller -another PHP script-  which will handle the rest of the request. Investigate `index.php` and see how it process the `route` parameter

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCart is built as an MVC (model-view-controller) application.  So when you see `route=checkout/cart`, that tells you how to get to the controller file

`catalog/controller/checkout/cart.php`

and you can deduce how to get to other files (model and view) from that. For example, the view is

`view/theme/default/template/checkout/cart.tpl`

So to redesign the checkout page, start with the view file.